# Drop down menu to display and hide input fields

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to build a form where the user selects their preferred method of contact and only that method is required/visible. So the email and phone input fields are initially hidden then when they select phone or email only that field is displayed below.

http://jsfiddle.net/PeytonGregory/de66edpj/

```
<script>
$('#contact-method').change(function(){
var selected_item = $(this).val()
if(selected_item == "email"){
    $('#email').val("").removeClass('hidden');
    $('#phone').val("").removeClass('required');
}if(selected_item == "phone"){
    $('#phone').val("").removeClass('hidden');
    $('#email').val("").removeClass('required');
}else{
    $('#phone').val(selected_item).addClass('hidden');
    $('#email').val(selected_item).addClass('hidden');
}
});
</script>




<label>Preferred Method of Contact?</label>
<select name="contact-method" class="selectfield" id="contact-method">
<option value="">Please Select...</option>
<option value="phone">Phone</option>
<option value="email">E-mail</option>
</select>
<input type='text' id="phone" placeholder="Phone" class="hidden required" />
<input type='text' id="email" placeholder="E-mail" class="hidden required" />

<input name="contactus" type="submit" class="submit" id="contactus" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: What exactly do you need assistance with? Your example shows it working only with the telephone dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

You've made a couple of mistakes in your javascript, below I have posted the corrected js.

Firstly you forgot to add `else` after the second `if` statement, secondly you need to add the hidden class to the non selected option so that it will hide one option while showing the other.

```
$('#contact-method').change(function(){
    var selected_item = $(this).val()
    if(selected_item == "email"){
        $('#email').val("").removeClass('hidden');
        $('#phone').val(selected_item).addClass('hidden');
        $('#phone').val("").removeClass('required');
    } else if(selected_item == "phone"){
        $('#phone').val("").removeClass('hidden');
        $('#email').val(selected_item).addClass('hidden');
        $('#email').val("").removeClass('required');
    }else{
        $('#phone').val(selected_item).addClass('hidden');
        $('#email').val(selected_item).addClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use elseif and add hidden to not selected.

```
    $('#contact-method').change(function() {
        var selected_item = $(this).val();
        if (selected_item === "email") {
            $('#email').val("").removeClass('hidden');
            $('#phone').val("").removeClass('required').addClass('hidden');

        } else if (selected_item == "phone") {
            $('#phone').val("").removeClass('hidden');
            $('#email').val("").removeClass('required').addClass('hidden');
        } else {
            $('#phone').val(selected_item).addClass('hidden');
            $('#email').val(selected_item).addClass('hidden');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you have given us, I can only guess that you want the appropriate input field to show if selected from the dropdown?

You were almost there. You were just forgetting to add the `.addClass('hidden');` to both inputs. Oh also, you only had 2 `if` statements and an `else`, I changed the second `if` to an `else if` to keep it looping through.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/de66edpj/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the idea is really to hide other `<input>`s except selected one, then code can be much shorter and flexible for as many options as you want:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/de66edpj/4/)

```
$('#contact-method').change(function()
{
    $('.inputs').addClass('hidden').removeClass('required');
    var selected_item = $(this).val();
    $('#' + selected_item).val("").removeClass('hidden').addClass('required');
});
```

Note: I added class `inputs` to all related `<input>`s.